# How to diff all changes by an author in an SVN branch?

Tags: svn, diff

As part of a code review, I need to review all the changes made by a single person to an svn branch. Is there a single command that can do this? Or will I have to just go through each revision marked with their name one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is probably the easiest way to do it; you can `Show log` for the branch's directory, make sure `stop-on-copy` is enabled, then use the search box to filter by author.

From the command line, I suspect you have some log parsing and a little script-fu to do. One way would be to have a script call `svn log` with the `--xml` switch, then use some command-line XML processing tools ([like Python](http://blog.mikepan.com/svn-log-parsing-and-analysis-fun/)) to filter only the revisions committed by the reviewee. From there, it's a short hop to go from revision numbers to diffs for each revision.